# Cannot Serialize SolidColorBrush

Tags: .net, wpf, serialization

Error message that I cannot serialize a class because cannot serialize SolidColorBrush

The class has a public property of Brush

Is there a fix?

It is more complex.
I tried using a backing property that can be serialized
Problem is that I also need to Freeze the HighLight so I can be created on a BackgroundWorker
If I use a serializable backing property for HighLight then Highlight.Freeze fails

```
[Serializable()]
public class WordIdLenHightlight : Object
{
    private string highlightHex;
    public Int32 ID { get; private set; }
    public Byte Len { get; private set; }
    //[NonSerialized]
    public Brush Highlight { get;  private set; }
    //{ if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(highlightHex)) return null; else return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(highlightHex)); }
    public string HighlightHex { get { return highlightHex; } }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(obj is WordIdLenHightlight)) return false;
        WordIdLenHightlight comp = (WordIdLenHightlight)obj;
        return (comp.ID == this.ID);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public WordIdLenHightlight(WordIdLenHightlight w) 
    { 
        ID = w.ID; Len = w.Len; 
        Highlight = w.Highlight;
        highlightHex = w.Highlight.ToString();
        Highlight.Freeze(); 
    }
    public WordIdLenHightlight(Int32 id, byte len, Brush highlight) 
    { 
        ID = id; Len = len; 
        Highlight = highlight; 
        //highlightHex = Highlight.ToString();
        Highlight.Freeze(); 
    }
    public WordIdLenHightlight(Int32 id, byte len, string HighlightHex) 
    {
        highlightHex = HighlightHex;
        ID = id; 
        Len = len;
        Highlight = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(highlightHex));
        Highlight.Freeze();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say how you're serializing the class, but you can probably decorate the `Brush` property or its backing field by an attribute such as `NonSerialized` or `XmlIgnore`.

You might want to serialize some other information than enables you to reconstruct the Brush on deserialization, for example, its color.

Comment: Thanks Joe,  I will try that and serialize the hex.  If I have problems I will post the code.

Comment: The fix was to remove Brush altogether and make the classes using this class convert the hex to a Brush

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It breaks the background worker even it I try and create the brush from the hex and then freeze it.  But it ran fine for a while and that is why I marked the answer as correct.

Comment: Old post, but if you guys are still around... It's quite an easy solution for SolidColorBrush's, just store the hex values. But for gradient brushes it's quite a bit more information to store. Is it possible for force a serialization of a non-serializable complex type?